# How to configure Mathjax in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, mathjax

We have a requirement to display the equations in mobile App which we are developing in IONIC 2.

Is anyone else tried the same and it's working?

How to include external JavaScript libraries in IONIC 2?

Comment: Hi, Could you solve the problem?

Comment: yeah we tried and it's working fine

Comment: Can you please help me out with this too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried Mathjax in sample Ionic App and it's working fine.
https://github.com/PrithiviRajG/IONIC2MathJaxImpl is the link for the sample project I tried, it's currently working as online Mathjax impletation i.e., it will work only with internet. I wanted it to make it offline, you are open to make changes to the code and make it offline and others can benefit on it.

Comment: cdn.mathjax.org has been retired. Check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.